# Simplest jQuery .ajax cannot find json file

Tags: jquery, json, iis

I have the following jQuery hosted in an IIS directory:

```
$(function () {
    $.ajax({
        "url": "sample.json",
        "type": "get",
        "dataType": "json",
        "success": function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        "error": function(jqXHR, status, error) {
            console.log("status:",status, "error", error);
        }
   }) ;
});
```

When I browse the html file, I get this in the JS console:

```
GET http://localhost/Ajax/sample.json 404 (Not Found) jquery-1.9.0.min.js:3
status: error error Not Found app.js:18
```

Its right in the directory. When I use /sample.json, I get:

```
GET http://localhost/sample.json 404 (Not Found) jquery-1.9.0.min.js:3
status: error error Not Found
```

How do I get it to find the local file and execute the ajax call?

Comment: Can you access the file directly by typing the URL in the address bar using your browser? If yes, what URL do you use for it?

Comment: yes but it can't deal with it The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map. http://localhost/Ajax/sample.json

Comment: Then, now you know what to do

Answer (score 6):

Since this is IIS, you're likely getting a subtype of 404 error, the 404.3 error—from a missing MIME map. JSON files are not registered as something IIS will serve by default. Go into INETMGR and add the extension to your MIME maps.

(web site — MIME Types — Add — json : application/json)

[image]

Comment: Yup, that was it! Thanks! Marked the answer

Answer (score 0):

Also remember if you file has got extension ".json" , then it must contain **proper json object**, otherwise your request will fail...